# Bash Script Help "if (user input) = then (var) ="

Tags: bash

I a writing a script to cherry pick all open changes from Gerrit. I found one that works sort of, though I need to be able to change inputs so that I do not have a script for each repo hardcoded with that specific repo's information.

```
#! /bin/sh
REMOTE="${1-review}"

ssh -p 29418 user@gerrit.remote.com gerrit query --format=text --patch-sets status:open branch:XXX project:XXX | grep revision: | awk '{print $2;}' | while read ID

do
    git fetch "${REMOTE}" && git cherry-pick "${ID}"

done
```

Now I have been able to pick open changes successfully but I am trying to make it so I can pass input to change username, branch, project and remote. With the current method I need to enter my username, project, branch, and remote manually into the script. Then it is only good for that specific repo.

I have been having trouble with `if`/`then` statements. I know as it looks now none of the things I am asking for are coded, I wanted to provide someone with a working model though.

I did change username and the particular details, easy enough for someone to use this script themselves to cherry-pick by inserting the requisite information.

If I do something like this:

```
PROJECT="$1"

if [ "$1" = "XX" ]; then
  "$PROJECT="project:name of project"
```

Then bash returns `XX command not found`. I am not trying to make it a command I want it to be input to be inserted into the ssh command later on. Also I am trying to not only use `if` but also `else if` so that `PROJECT` can be whatever is input.

I think I am almost there though completely stumped at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $1 is equal to "XX". Your code:

```
PROJECT="$1"
```

will assign PROJECT=XX. Next,

```
if [ "$1" = "XX" ]; then
```

is true, "then" clause will be executed. This clause is:

```
"$PROJECT="project:name of project"
```

that tries to execute command "XX=...", causing "command not found"

Suggestion, remove $ on this line, as in:

```
 PROJECT="project:name of project"
```